MQTT multiple subscribers to one topic
I've recently started using the MQTT broker in AWS, where one device receives messages to control a wind turbine. Now, I wanted to expand this control by connecting a second device to the broker topic. However, I've noticed that when two devices are connected, they seem to constantly 'fight' for connection, pushing each other off. I thought MQTT could support multiple subscribers? When I turn off one of the devices, everything works as expected.

Dunno about AWS's MQTT Broker, but i never had such problems with a Broker like mosquitto. In general your scenario is supported. Perhaps amazon limits the connection for you user/topics?

Didn't you restrict the number of active connection to your broker?

MQTT clients must each have a unique Client ID. The MQTT spec says that if a second client connects with the same client id the broker MUST disconnect the first.
Clients can share the same username/password, but they can not share client ids.
Most MQTT client libraries will generate random client ids if none are set.

thanks, any idea how to configure this in aws ?

Ask a new question and show your code, without knowing the library you are using and how it's impossible to answer.
